# How to form upload a file which is downloaded using Extjs rest (AJAX ) call

Tags: extjs, file-upload, extjs5

I need to upload a file which i download using Extjs Ajax call.

Below is how i am trying to do it.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/someRemoteCloudRepository',    // url of remote cloud repository from which i download file.
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
    },
    success: function(response) {   // upon success, i need to upload this file into my server application
       var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            items: [{
                xtype: 'filefield',
                name: 'file_path',
            }]
        });
        form.down('filefield').setValue(response.responseText); // Is this the right way to set the downloaded file content ?

        var url = 'uploadFile?id=' + '123'; 
        var params = "size=" + getFileSize(); // how can I get the response data size ?

        if (form.isValid()) {
            form.submit({
                url: url,
                params: params,
                timeout: 60,
                waitMsg: 'Uploading file...',
                success: function(formBasic, action) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('', 'Upload Failed. Please try again');
                },
                failure: function(response, opts) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('', 'Upload Failed. Please try again');
                }
            });
        }
    },

    failure: function(response) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Failed to download file from remote cloud repo.');
    }
});
```

I am able to download file from remote cloud server and i see the data in `response.responseText` of `success: function(response)`.

Then, I create a simple form with a `filefield` and set its value with the responseText and do a form submit. In the inspector tool i see the multipart request being sent , but the status remains in 'pending' state or request times out.

How can i upload a file once i download from remote source ?

Is the approach i have tried correct ? if not how can i do it ?